# until [it had] risen

Tags: past-participles, participle-clauses

Could "subject + had" sequence be omitted in the following? If it's possible only in b, why can't the same happen to a?

> a. The soldiers remained in the room until **they had** witnessed the execution of the hostage.

> b. The cake was kept outside until **it had** risen.

Comment: I don't think you *can* omit **it had** in sentence B.  I think you can only omit **subject** + *to be* in a passive clause, like "We will remain here until (we are) needed."

Comment: Off-topic but cakes left outside don't rise. A cake is already baked, if left outside it can become dry,  stale or grow mouldy but not rise. So sentence b sounds odd (logically speaking) to me.

Comment: Also, any dough that is left to prove must be kept covered in a warm place until (it has) risen.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no rule in English that allows **subject + "had"** to be removed.

In your second example, the resulting sentence *happens to be* correct, but it's actually an abbreviated form of:

> The cake was kept outside until ***it was*** risen.

We can see that it's not "it had risen" because if I change the tense of the main clause, it still makes sense as "it [be-verb] risen", and can still be reduced:

> Keep the cake outside until (it is) risen.
>
> *<del>Keep the cake outside until (it had) risen.</del>

Omitting "subject + be-verb" is sometimes allowable. [This site](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_TAdgdaXx41QDFfJmUv_JqtnzDUSpMJZ/edit?amp;ouid=105695281640130916489&rtpof=true&sd=true) gives an imprecise version of the rule:

> You can omit the subject and and the verb form of “to be”
>
> 1. if the subject is clear in context, and
> 2. if the omitted subject is present in the main clause as the subject or object

Answer (score 0):

No, [subject + had] cannot normally be omitted.

However, in recipes some words may be omitted for brevity. Referring to yeast dough, the instructions might say *Leave in a warm place until risen*, omitting *it has*.